# How to obtain a framed plot with blank space where data that would normally extend to the blank space?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a large set of data where every line is in the form:

```
{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
```

The values in column `x2` cab be much larger than 150.

I would like to plot the data in a framed list plot, using on the row where $x2\in[0,\, 150]$. I would also like the frame to be larger than the `PlotRange` specified interval, in order to label the different parts of the data (there are 7 of them) and for a label to appear next to a line using `Epilog`.

I have tried to use `Epilog` to label the lines without enlarging the frame and the labels are invisible. I have tried to use `PlotRangePadding` to enlarge the frame, but it enlarges the plot range too.

I have tried to select the data manually with the following code:

```
    list={};
    For[i = 1, i < Length[data],
     If[data[[i, 2]] > 0 && data[[i, 2]] < 150, 
      AppendTo[list, data[[i]]]];
     i + 10]
```

but Mathematica crashes (the `i + 10` is to reduce the data set).

Is there a way to obtain a plot with a plot range between 0 and 150, and the frame between 0 and 200, in order to have a white space where I can display the labels with `Epilog`?

Comment: `Select[x2, # <= 150]`

Comment: `AppendTo` is very inefficient. If you are collecting data, use `Reap` and `Sow`. Also, `For` is way (I mean WAY) slower than `Do`, a mathematica-native version of `For`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the value of `i` never changes (the last `i + 10` does nothing), resulting in an infinite loop and crash. That being said, I believe `Select` is a better option to use here. That is, `Select[data, AllTrue[#, 0<=#<=150&]&]`

Comment: ok, I'll try that. I hadn't realized about the infinite loop

Comment: One question, by "with the data only between x2=[0,150]", do you mean you want to find and collect `{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}` all of whose `x2` values are in $[0, 150]$, or trim `x2` so that all values fall in that interval?

Comment: One more thing, by stating `data[[i, 2]] > 0` and `data[[i, 2]] < 150`, you are effectively trying to compare a list with an integer. _Mathematica_ does not allow that. You could use [`AllTrue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html).

Comment: I mean to find and collect the data so that in the end I only have the data that have x2 lying between 0 and 150

Comment: Pertaining to your question concerning making annotations with Epilog, it is unclear to me what you actually want to plot and how you want the final plot to look. Can you restate you problem with a clearer description of the plot? I have a feeling that the For-loop issue you have inserted is not relevant to your plotting issue.

Comment: not really, but the resolution of the For-loop will do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer only addresses your problem with `For`. Note that `For` should have the form

> $\qquad$For[*index-initializer*, *exit-test*, *index-incrementer,* *code-body*]

which means your code will work when rewritten as

```
sample = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i += 10, 
  If[data[[i, 2]] => 0 && data[[i, 2]] <= 150, AppendTo[sample, data[[i]]]]];
sample
```

but in Mathematica the following expression will produce the same result

```
Select[data[[;; ;; 10]], 0 <= #[[2]] <= 150. &]
```

and is not only more concise but executes much faster. Since the above may a bit cryptic for a beginner (and your question makes it almost certain you are beginner), here is a less concise but more easily understood equivalent.

```
Block[{test},
  test[row_] := 0 <= row[[2]] <= 150.;
  Select[Take[data, {1, -1, 10}], test]]
```